# How do you get a block from a block in creative minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im trying rn to explore the new nether (Snapshot 20w06a) and i want to get the blocks on the ground in my inventory w/out searching thru the entire creative menu. Also, i use MC java with ***NO MOUSE***.

Answer (score 3):

Open the settings menu and go into the controls tab. There is an action called pick block. Set it to whatever you want (default is middle mouse button I think) and then you can press that key while looking at a specific block to obtain that block.

Comment: tysm! it worked

Comment: @GuestYT please mark the answer as accepted so others can see that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

With no mouse, tap on your trackpad with 3 fingers at the same time. If this doesn't work, go to whatever settings your computer has and turn on the ability to 3 finger tap to "3rd click."